# Scripting over ssh through putty on windows

Tags: mysql, ssh, putty

I need to script a mysql restore of a linux machine from a windows machine. I have putty and  I know it has ssh capability. Here is what I have:

```
C:\Progra~1\Putty\putty.exe -ssh root@10.1.2.3 && mysql -u USER -pPASS db < /tmp/dump.sql
```

My problem in writing a script is that putty opens a new window and transfers control there, so anything coming after

```
putty.exe -ssh
```

doesn't do anything.

Comment: PuTTY probably isn't the tool you want to use here.

Comment: writing a script with your root password in plaintext is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, it won't be root, just like the password won't be PASS :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-m` option to specify a file which contains a command to run on the remote connection.

Example:

```
C:\Progra~1\Putty\putty.exe -ssh -m C:\cmd.txt root@10.1.2.3
```

Contents of `C:\cmd.txt`

```
 mysql -u USER -pPASS db < /tmp/dump.sql
```

From the [Putty Documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/puttydoc.txt):

> 3.8.3.6 `-m': read a remote command or script from a file
>
> The `-m' option performs a similar function to the`Remote command'
>   box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section
>   4.18.1). However, the `-m' option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put
>   multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in
>   sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and
>   cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is known
>   *not* to work with certain `embedded' servers, such as Cisco routers.
>
> This option is not available in the file transfer tools PSCP and
>   PSFTP.