# Run unix commands using C#

Tags: c#, unix

Is It possible to connect to unix server and run a shell scrip using c# in Windows Forms , and retrieve the output of the script in some textbox?

I would also like to remotely connect a desktop using code and search for several files there. Kindly let me know how to do it.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: You want an ssh library for shell access (or execute external ssh program), and a library for remote desktop protocol for remote desktop . Or if you just want file access to desktop folder, then you need a protocol for file access.

Comment: Another great library is [ssh.net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) which supports both ssh and sftp and has many other specific features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

Typically the Unix machine would be running some sort of secure shell (SSH) server which would allow you to connect with a specific username/password and run your shell script.

In order to run this from your windows forms application you could either integrate a software library like Granados from http://granados.sourceforge.net/ to connect and run the script or you could simply setup a client like PuTTY to run a script and spawn that as an external process, ie:

```
Process.Start("C:\Putty\putty.exe -ssh -m C:\myScript.txt remoteUser@192.168.1.1);
```

You can see [Scripting over ssh through putty on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736683/scripting-over-ssh-through-putty-on-windows) for more info on setting up your scripts. It sounds like you would have to save the output from putty to a file and then read that with your WinForms app if you went this direction.

The other alternative is to add a reference to a library like granados or simply use the NuGet package manager to add the 'ssh.net' to your winforms application. There is an example at http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/285219 where they open a connection to the server, execute a command and read the results all using the ssh.net libraries.

For the second question it depends on how the remote PCs are connected to you. If they are on the same shared network (eg: intranet at work) you can setup network shares on the machines you are interested in and inspect the filesystem directly by using paths like:
 `System.IO.File.GetAttributes(@"\\hostname\shareName\filename.txt");`

If the remote machines are actually at remote locations it becomes much more difficult and you will need to use a remote desktop library or have the remote machines setup FTP servers or something similar for you to browse the filesystem.