# How can I comfortably design a Linux based terminal application from my Windows laptop?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ssh

I have a Centos 6.4 (minimal) system configured like a “NAS drive.”

I would like to design a Linux based terminal application on my Window laptop, then build/run it from my “NAS Drive.”  It is annoying to keep switching to Putty, running the build script then testing the program itself!

The source code is stored/edited over a Samba share so everything’s already in the right place.

Is there a c++ editor for Windows that can build/run the application with the touch of a button (F9)?  Or a batch script or something for Windows that automates a series of SSH commands?

Comment: This maybe? It is a sort of virtual linux environment http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: I probably entirely misunderstood your question, but you know putty can [run remote ssh scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736683/scripting-over-ssh-through-putty-on-windows), right?

Comment: I want Putty to automatically log in to my account (I understand and accept the sercurity risks) then automatically run a series of commands.

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux on your laptop ? Then, use your laptop's Linux system to develop your Linux application!

Comment: I prefer Windows for both normal computer usage and a developing environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your shoes, I'd use [eclipse with cdt](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) and [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: I tried eclipse, the interface looks messy and when trying to setup the remote application build via SSH, it only lets me use my Windows username.

Comment: Well, I've used UltraEdit (http://www.ultraedit.com) for this sort of thing before too - more light weight, but not free.  You can program your own "F9" pretty easy.  You'll still need to solve your ssh issue:  it takes a -l argument to set the user name (the one with cygwin I mean).  Good luck with your project!